# Multiple Fragments in Single Activity onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am struck with MultipleFragments in SingleActivity onSavedInstanceState.

I have saved fragment status and try to reload current fragment in MainActivity class but I am unable to load CurrentFragment.

Step1: onSavedInstanceState() method I fetch the current fragment from the container

Step2: onCreate() method I try to reload the current fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String title_action_bar=savedInstanceState.getString("headerTitle");
            manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment MyFragment = (Fragment) manager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "currentFragment");
            if(MyFragment!=null)
            {
                FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, MyFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

        }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        displayMovieFragments(R.id.nav_popular);
    }


    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Save the values you need into "outState"
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
        manager.putFragment(outState, "currentFragment", currentFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        displayMovieFragments(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
    private void displayMovieFragments(int itemId)
    {
        String actionBarTitle="";
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (itemId)
        {
            case R.id.nav_popular:
                fragment=new MostPopular();
                actionBarTitle="Most Popular Movies";
                break;
            case R.id.nav_top_rated:
                fragment=new TopRated();
                actionBarTitle="Top Rated Movies";
                break;
            case R.id.nav_favourite:
                fragment=new FavoriteMovies();
                actionBarTitle="My Favorite Movies";
                break;
        }
        if(fragment!=null)
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(actionBarTitle);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error? Please post.

Comment: what if the savedInstanceState is null (Like when the app runs for the first time) ? The complete fragment transaction code won't even run in that case and perhaps this is the reason you're unable to load the fragment.

Comment: @Daniel the error is "i have saved fragment status and try to reload current fragment in MainActivity class but i am unable to load CurrentFragment"

Answer (score 0):

1. This should be the first thing in `onCreate()`

   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
2. Do all your things except the fragment part inside `onCreate()`
3. At the end of `onCreate()`

> 

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
          // load fragment with saved state
     }
     else
     {
            //load  fragment with fresh state
     }
```

4. `displayMovieFragment()` also loads another fragment so what are you trying to do loading two fragments unconditionally? This should be called from the `onNavigationItemSelectedListener` of the NavigationDrawer which you have already handled. So remove `displayMovieFragment()` from `onCreate()`